# Difficulty understanding Gemara's logic about number of necessary sukkah walls

Tags: talmud-gemara, sukkah, masechet-sukkah

## Some background information

At [Sukkah 6b](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=1109&size=2), the *gemara* presents a dispute between R' Shimon and the Rabanan about how many walls are necessary for a *sukkah* to have.  The Rabanan hold that a *sukkah* needs two full walls (at least 7 *tefachim* long) plus one wall of at least a *tefach*.  R' Shimon holds that a *sukkah* needs **three** full walls plus one wall of at least a *tefach*. The *gemara* attempts to explain the nature of their dispute.

The first possible explanation is that they dispute whether the כתיב (how a word is *written* in the Torah) or the קרי (how the word is *pronounced* when reading from the Torah) is considered more important.  They consider three times the word *sukkot* is written in the Torah. Twice it is *chaser* (the *vav* that makes the word plural is not included in the כתיב), and once it is *malei* (the *vav* is written).

Since the Rabanan hold that the כתיב is more important than the קרי, they count the instances of *sukkot* that are *chaser* (spelled סכת) as 1 and they count the instance that is *malei* (spelled סכות) as 2. So all-together they get 4 (סכת + סכת + סכות) and they subtract one because they hold that you do not make a *derasha* on the first instance of a word.  They are left with three, and they make the *derasha* that that means 3 walls for the *sukkah* and they say that there is a *halacha l'Moshe miSinai* that one of the walls only needs to be one *tefach* long.

R' Shimon, on the other hand, holds that the קרי is more important, so he counts each instance of the word *sukkot* as 2 for a total of 6 (סכות + סכות + סכות). He subtracts one instance of the word *sukkot* because he doesn't make a *derasha* on that instance and so he's left with a total of 4 (סכות + סכות), meaning 4 walls. And he holds (like the Rabanan) that there is a *halacha l'Moshe miSinai* that one of the walls only needs to be one *tefach*.

---

## My Question

After all of that background information, here is my question.  After the above discussion, the *gemara* gives a series of alternative explanations about the nature of the dispute between R' Shimon and the Rabanan.  The first alternative explanation leaves me baffled, though.

It says that alternatively, we can even say that both the Rabanan and R' Shimon hold that the קרי is more important.  So they both count a total of 6.  Subtract one instance of סכות because we don't make a *derasha* on the first instance of the word, and we're left with 4. Here's the part I don't understand:

> מר סבר סככה בעיא קרא ומר סבר סככה לא בעיא קרא

Based on Rashi, I understand that to mean that the Rabanan hold that we would not have been able to know that a *sukkah* needs *skhakh* without one of these instances, while R' Shimon holds that we don't need to use one of the instances to show that a *sukkah* needs *skhakh* since it wouldn't be called a *sukkah* if it didn't need *skhakh*.

So for R' Shimon, the case is the same as above; he has a total of 4 walls, and there is a *halacha l'Moshe miSinai* that one of them only needs to be 1 *tefach*. But I don't understand how the Rabanan come out to 3 walls based on this understanding. It seems to me that the Rabanan require two of the uses of *sukkot* for other things, and they are only left with one.  That should be two walls, not three.

So what about the Rabanan's position according to this second explanation of the dispute am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I couldn't really come up with a good title for this question. Suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I think the title's fine. Why don't you just assume that the Rabanan apply one of the four notional instances of *sukka* that are derived from the two extra instances of "*sukkot*" to *sechach*, leaving three?

Comment: @IsaacMoses That didn't seem right to me because why would they subtract 2 because we don't make a _derasha_ on the first _sukkot_ but then subtract 1 for the _skhakh_? What's the difference between the two cases such that we would subtract 1 for one of them and 2 for the other one?

Comment: I suppose perhaps since the _skhakh_ **is** a _derasha_ according to the Rabanan, maybe that's the reason. The 4 notional instances of _sukkah_ means 4 _derashot_. Three of them are for the three walls and one of them is for the _skhakh_? Does that make any sense?

Comment: That's how I'd read it. Why not?

Comment: @IsaacMoses No reason why not. It just hadn't really occurred to me. I was thinking that the _skhakh_ requires one of the words in the same way the other issue required one of the words. Perhaps write up an answer? I'm not sure if the question is too trivial for there to be any discussion in the Rishonim, but if you can find some evidence that that's the _peshat_ that would be even better.

Answer (score 4):

Art Scroll 6b2 goes into more detail.

All agree that the pronounced form has primacy so that of the 6 (3*2) we are left with four (2*2) allusions. The rabbanan then say that one of the four allusions is required for schach leaving three allusions. (note 23). The reason is that as once the two of the actual references are available for learning an allusion, we can use each of the four allusions for teaching something. This is the reason for the machlokes on what we use the fourth allusion to teach.

Comment: got it. So it's basically what I said [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/64748/difficulty-understanding-gemaras-logic-about-number-of-necessary-sukkah-walls/64752#comment178874_64748). Makes sense.